# Poor Hygiene vs. Cross-species transmission?

Tags: virology, mutations, coronavirus

Did a poor hygiene at wet Chinese markets add anything to equation to trigger critical mutation of COVID-19 helping it to transmit the virus from bats/pangolins to humans?

If not, would it spread to humans anyway (even if those markets were clean and spotless) since people over there were in frequent contact with such viruses (right before preparing those wild animals as meals), which would give the virus enough time for necessary adjustment/mutation?

> Even though I mentioned COVID-19, I think the question could be
>   generally applied to any mutation of a virus right before it transmits
>   from animals to humans. It happened many times in our past and I am
>   quite confident there are many researches out there related to this
>   topic.

*I'm specifically interested in deciphering whether **poor hygiene on those wet markets** helps propelling such cross-species transmission.*

*Could it be the virus was already transmittable to humans whilst it was still in those bats/pangolins without any prior mutation whatsoever?*

Please elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered this most recent study that fully answers my question. 
The reason appears not to be related with the hygiene itself, but the **high stress level of animals that are put into cages close to humans**. Therefore, the hygiene level seems irrelevant for such virus transmission from animals to humans, as long as it doesn't increase the stress level of each individual animal:

[Global shifts in mammalian population trends reveal key predictors of virus spillover risk](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2019.2736)